# ROR Regex. I am trying to validate that the first and fourth characters in the string are any numbers other than 0 or 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby

I cannot find a solution on google or SO

This works for the first character

```
validates :number, format: { with: /\A[2-9]/ }
```

and this works for the fourth character

```
validates :number, format: { with: /\A...[2-9]/ }
```

But for the life of me i cannot figure out how to sort of merge these to validate both. Please help

Comment: BTW, this will also have `numericality: true`

Comment: The post title requirement doesn't match these regexes. Do you mean a digit that isn't 0 or 1 or any character that isn't 0 or 1? `\A[^01]..[^01]` or `\A[2-9]..[2-9]`

Comment: @ggorlen thanks, i updated. Does it make sense now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
validates :number, format: { with: /\A[2-9].{2}[2-9]/m }
```

**Explanation**

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \A                       the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [2-9]                    any character of: '2' to '9'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  .{2}                     any character (2 times)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [2-9]                    any character of: '2' to '9'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [\w\W]{2} to indicate any 2 characters:

```
/A[2-9][\w\W]{2}[2-9]/
```